# Loopback filters - on related models with scope

Tags: loopbackjs

I have the below models defined in loopback,
Jobs
Tasks
Users

where Jobs can have multiple tasks to be performed by one or more users.

I am trying to query using the below, where I want to find Jobs filtered by a certain organization, tasks which are of a certain status and include user information. Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong with my query here -

> http://localhost:3000/api/m_tasks/?filter[include][r_jobs]&filter[include][r_users]&filter[where][status]=Completed&filter[where][r_jobs][organization]=12345